# How to get outer 2 points of 3 colinear points

Tags: geometry

If I have points $(0,0), (1,1), (2,2)$. They are colinear, thus I only want $(0,0)$ and $(2,2)$ in the end. What should be the best way to get this?

Another example. I have points (0,0) and (2,2) and I add a point (-1,-1). My original 2 outer points were (0,0) and (2,2), now I want it to be (-1, -1) and (2,2).

Comment: I don't see the problem. From your examples, you seem to clearly know what you want and how to get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the line is parallel to the $y$ axis, you can just take the points with maximum and minimum $x$ coordinates.  You can detect that by seeing that the $x$ values are all the same, in which case you use the minimum and maximum $y$ coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, when you have points $\vec{p}_1$, $\vec{p}_2$, and $\vec{p}_3$, calculate their [Euclidean distances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) $d_{12}=\lVert\vec{p}_1 - \vec{p}_2\rVert$, $d_{13}=\lVert\vec{p}_1-\vec{p}_3\rVert$, and $d_{23}=\lVert\vec{p}_2-\vec{p}_3\rVert$:

- If $d_{12} = d_{13} + d_{23}$, then the three are collinear, with $\vec{p}_3$ in the middle, so you can remove $\vec{p}_3$.
- If $d_{13} = d_{12} + d_{23}$, then the three are collinear, with $\vec{p}_2$ in the middle, so you can remove $\vec{p}_2$
- If $d_{23} = d_{12} + d_{13}$, then the three are collinear, with $\vec{p}_1$ in the middle, so you can remove $\vec{p}_1$.
- Otherwise, the three points are not collinear.

This works in higher dimensions as well. You don't even need to check for degenerate points (points with exact same coordinates), the above suffices even for the corner cases. For 2D, if
$$\begin{align}
\vec{p}_1 &= \left ( x_1, y_1 \right ) \\
\vec{p}_2 &= \left ( x_2, y_2 \right ) \\
\vec{p}_3 &= \left ( x_3, y_3 \right ) \\
\end{align}$$
then
$$\begin{align}
d_{12} &= \sqrt{ (x_1 - x_2)^2 + (y_1 - y_2)^2 } \\
d_{13} &= \sqrt{ (x_1 - x_3)^2 + (y_1 - y_3)^2 } \\
d_{23} &= \sqrt{ (x_2 - x_3)^2 + (y_2 - y_3)^2 }
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the cosine law
to get the cosine
of each angle.

The point in the middle
will have an angle
close to $\pi$,
so its cosine will be about $-1$.

The other two points
will have an angle
close to zero,
so their cosine
will be about $1$.

Answer (score 0):

The approach by @RossMillikan is a good one, requiring just a few comparisons. Anyway, it can fail when the coordinates aren't exact (noisy) and the line is close to vertical.

You fix that by returning the points of minimum and maximum coordinate, on the axis where the difference is the largest. This avoids having to choose a tolerance.